# regex lines that matchs a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like a regex pattern to match all lines in a text file that has the follow pattern:

```
TcQuery {dynamic_content} Alias "{dynamic_content}" New
```

If the text file has these two lines:

```
//tcquery c_query alias "qrybklog" new           <= This one shouldn´t be found because there is two backslashes before TcQuery.

tcquery c_query alias "qrybklog" new             <= I want a pattern to match this line
```

I´ve tried this but both lines are matched:

```
        var prw = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\backlog.prw", Encoding.ASCII);

        prw = "//TcQuery c_query Alias teste1 new";
        prw = "\nTcQuery c_query Alias teste2 new";
        prw = "\nTcQuery c_query Alias teste3 new";
        prw = "\n//TcQuery c_query Alias teste4 new";
        var regexTcQuery = new Regex("TcQuery+[ *]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]+[ *]+alias+[ *]+[0-9a-zA-Z_\"]+[ *]new$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        var resultTcQuery = regexTcQuery.Matches(prw);
```

Comment: Is an arbitrary amount of whitespace in the line (including at the beginning, between lexical tokens and at the end) allowed?

Comment: Matches a pattern as opposed to...  what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `singleline` and `ignorecase` option with this regex

```
(?<!\/\/)\s*?\btcquery\b(.*?)\balias\b.*?new
```

---

`(?<!\/\/)` checks for `//` before `tcquery`

`.*?` is a lazily matches 0 to many characters.If you use `.*` then it would match the last `tcqurey` skipping ibetween `tcquery` matches

`\b` is a `non-word` boundary.This allows us to match separate words

`\s` matches `0` to `many` space which can be any of the `[\n\r\t\f]`

---

If you want to get the c_query text you can do this

```
List<string> lst=Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<!\/\/)\s*?\btcquery\b(.*?)\balias\b.*?new").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: But in some cases there are tabs and spaces before tcquery

Comment: @will i have included that part

Comment: prw += "//TcQuery c_query Alias \"teste1\" new";
            prw += "\nTcQuery c_query Alias \"teste2\" new";
            var regexTcQuery = new Regex(@"^\s*\btcquery\b.*\balias\b.*new\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);   No matches are found.

Comment: var prw = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\backlog.prw", Encoding.ASCII);
            prw = "";
            prw += "//TcQuery c_query Alias \"teste1\" new";
            prw += "\nTcQuery c_query Alias \"teste2\" new";
            var regexTcQuery = new Regex(@"(?<![^\\])\s*?\btcquery\b.*?\balias\b.*?new", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var resultTcQuery = regexTcQuery.Matches(prw);

Its still not working...

Comment: For each match found... Id like to get 'c_query' text after tcQuery:   TcQuery c_query Alias "TESTE" NEW

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the full line (without any sub-groups), you could use:

```
^tcquery.*$
```

The `^` indicates that the text starts at the beginning of the string; since `tcquery` is the text immediately following, lines that start with `//` will be ignored.

If there are is any whitespace before `tcquery`, you can match this with `\s*`:

```
^\s*tcquery.*$
```

If you have lines that can begin with `tcquery` but don't necessarily follow the format you specified, you can update the pattern with:

```
^\s*tcquery.*alias.*new.*?$
```

To match the "dynamic" content portions of the line(s) into groups, you should be able to use:

```
^\s*tcquery\s+(.*)\s+alias\s+"(.*)"\s+new.*?$
```

Also, worth noting, you should have the ignore-case regex option enabled for each of my above-examples.

Comment: But in some cases there are tabs and spaces before tcquery

Comment: @will Updated with a `\s*` to match the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\/\/])tcquery (.*) alias \"(.*)\" new$/i
```

if your language does not support /i for caseless matching, then switch the regex to:

```
([^\/\/])TcQuery (.*) Alias \"(.*)\" New$
```

Comment: Ah, now the c# tag is added, this answer probably doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^tcquery [^ ]+ alias "[^"]+" new
```

it's an amateur one but the main idea is that the line must start with tcquery.